# Eclipse Luna dark theme doesn't show JS properly

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-pdt, eclipse-luna

I downloaded the Eclipse Luna version of PDT today and switched to the dark theme. All my PHP files are now displayed with very clear syntax highlighting in the dark theme.

However, when I load my javascript files, it's impossible to see the text in the file as it's dark black on lighter black (see image). This happens only for the JS files as all of the CSS and HTML files in the project inherit the dark theme very nicely.

[image: Dark theme with JS]

I've restarted Eclipse applying the theme and the issue still remains. Any idea how I can get my JS file to work with this new version?

Comment: Forget the DarkTheme, it came with Luna but is not ready, many texts have poor contrast.

Comment: I'm agree. It shows terrible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest install eclipse color themes plugin: http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/

This plugin provide dark editor support for most popular eclipse plugins (css, js, xml)

Comment: Thank you for this, I've never seen this plugin before. Tried it out and works really well.

Comment: I tried this plugin - but for almost all dark themes my code looks like at the screenshot of the author of question. Any other advices?

Comment: JSDT 2.0 (Neon RC3 right now) support dark theme out of box. Will released after 2 weeks.

Comment: Dead link. Downvoting.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at:

https://github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme#syntax-highlighting-scheme-optional

and import the epf file.
This should solve your issue and similar ones, until a stylesheet for dark theme settings for syntax will be added to all Eclipse plugins packages.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have the VJET Javascript IDE installed as an Eclipse Plugin.  The color scheme you have looks exactly the same as what I was getting.  I solved it by uninstalling this plugin.  Go to Help -> Install New Software -> click "already installed" hyperlink, and see if you have it installed.  Click Uninstall.

Here are some things to check to determine is this is the problem.
Go to Eclipse Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations and check the default editor for Eclipse. If JVET is installed, VJET will be the default editor.  If you try to switch the javascript editor to be default, it won't let you do that option. The javascript editor should be taking in the appropriate color schemes by whatever theme you have installed.  I assume VJET has a fixed color schemes.

Go to Preferences -> Javascript -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring.  Check if the syntax in the preview box actually matches what is displayed on your javascript file.